# Qt SQL: how to differentiate between a double and an int?

Tags: c++, qt, integer, double

I use an SQLite database in Qt. When filling a QTableWidget with information, I want to check if values received as QVariant are integers, doubles, or strings:

```
// query something here, put in in var named 'query'
while(query.next()){
    // insert new row
    for (int i=0; i<columnCount; i++){
        if(query.value(i).toInt()!=0){
            //add integer table item with special sorting/formatting 
        }else if(query.value(i).toDouble()!=0){
            //add double table item with special sorting/formatting
        }else {
            //add standard qt table item
        }
    }
}
```

The problem is that double gets casted to integer when using *toInt()* and the other way round, which is why all numeric values are treated as integers or all as doubles, dependig on which one you test first.

Is there a possibility to properly check if the number is a double or an integer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To test the exact type stored in a `QVariant`, you can use the [type()](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmetatype.html#Type-enum) function and then switch on it:

```
switch(query.value(i).type()) {
case QMetaType::Int:
    // ....
    break;
case QMetaType::Double:
    // ...
    break;
}
```

The types can be found [here](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmetatype.html#Type-enum).

Also, perhaps @Victor's answer has its merit - I'm not sure how QtSQL handles the types.

Answer (score 1):

You must query `sqlite_master` for metadata.

You should run a separate query for field `type` with condition `name` as field name, and `tbl_name` as table name.

See here for available field types:

[SQLite Frequently Asked Questions](https://www.sqlite.org/faq.html)

Comment: I went with @Rostislav's answer, which seems to have solved the problem. Thank you anyway for your help, the link you provided still is very helpful.